# Contraseña en pagina php

Tags: php, html

Hola tengo el siguiente código para proteger una pagina php... pero aparece un notice que dice: undefined Index Password... como hago para corregirlo. Gracias

```
<?php 
$password = "123456";
if ($_POST['password'] != $password) { 
?>
<h2>Logueate</h2>
<form name="form" method="post" action="">
<input type="password" name="password"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Login"></form>
<?php 
}else{
?>
Contenido protegido
<?php 
} 
?>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Seguro que ese es el código y esta escrito tal cual lo usaste?, te pregunto por que el código no da el fallo que dices

Comment: Es un aviso que aparece encima del formulario.

Answer (score 2):

es porque en un primer momento `$_POST['password']` no existe, recien se va a generar cuando envies el formulario.

mejor seria verificar primero si es que existe con `isset`

```
<?php 
    $password = "123456";
    if (isset($_POST['password']) && $_POST['password'] != $password) {

    /*
    //sugerencia

    $password = $_POST['password'] ?? "";
    if ($password != "123456") {
    */
?>
        <h2>Logueate</h2>
        <form name="form" method="post" action="">
            <input type="password" name="password"><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Login"></form>
<?php 
    }else{
?>
        Contenido protegido
<?php 
    } 
?>
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu respuesta, te comento que al hacer la prueba el código que sugeriste, muestra directamente el Contenido protegido, y no así el formulario de de login. Gracias !